# HTML+CSS nested checkbox-style accordion: some items too long

Tags: html, css, navigation, accordion

I'm trying to make a multi-level accordion for a navigational `aside` in a page, and I'm finding that one type of element comes out too long: when changing the `background-color` on a hover, the highlighted background of that one extends into the main body of the page. This happens for a folder-type item (with child elements) that is itself a child of another folder.

In the [JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/qdyhkag7/11/), the problem is seen when comparing "Folder 3" to everything else. How do I get it to match?

```css
.accordion {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

aside {
  background-color: orange;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}

.label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

.label:hover,
.item:not(.has-children):hover {
  background-color: red;
}

.label-l1 {
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.label-l2 {
  padding-left: 40px;
}

.main {
  background-color: yellow;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: 170px;
  width: 200px;
}

.sub {
  display: none;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.input:checked~.sub {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <aside>
      <ul class="accordion">
        <li class="item has-children">
          <input class="input" type="checkbox" name="c1" id="c1">
          <label class="label" for="c1"><span>Folder 1</span></label>
          <ul class="sub sub-l1">
            <li class="item"><a href="" class="label-l1">Item 1</a></li>
            <li class="item"><a href="" class="label-l1">Item 2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="item has-children">
          <input class="input" type="checkbox" name="c2" id="c2">
          <label class="label" for="c2"><span>Folder 2</span></label>
          <ul class="sub sub-l1">
            <li class="item has-children">
              <input class="input" type="checkbox" name="c3" id="c3">
              <label class="label label-l1" for="c3"><span>Folder 3</span></label>
              <ul class="sub sub-l1">
                <li class="item"><a href="" class="label-l2">Item 3</a></li>
                <li class="item"><a href="" class="label-l2">Item 4</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </aside>
    <div class="main">
      <p>I must speak my mind about this.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is the parent element has a ***width*** of ***100%***, and the element has a ***padding*** of ***20px***, this is pushing the right side margin ***20px*** past the right border, add `box-sizing: border-box;` to `.label-l1` element, this will constrain any would be overflow inside the border and keep the background from overflowing outside the border.

```
.label-l1 {
  padding-left: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

***Note:** You can set this in a reset within your CSS so you do not have to fix all potential occurrences with border-sizing on other elements*

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```css
.accordion {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
aside {
  background-color: orange;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}
.input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}
.label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
.label:hover, .item:not(.has-children):hover {
  background-color: red;
}
.label-l1 {
  padding-left: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box; /* added this line of code */
}
.label-l2 {
  padding-left: 40px;
}
.main {
  background-color: yellow;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: 170px;
  width: 200px;
}
.sub {
  display: none;
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.input:checked ~ .sub {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <aside>
    <ul class="accordion">
      <li class="item has-children">
        <input class="input" type="checkbox" name="c1" id="c1">
        <label class="label" for="c1"><span>Folder 1</span></label>
        <ul class="sub sub-l1">
          <li class="item"><a href="" class="label-l1">Item 1</a></li>
          <li class="item"><a href="" class="label-l1">Item 2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="item has-children">
        <input class="input" type="checkbox" name="c2" id="c2">
        <label class="label" for="c2"><span>Folder 2</span></label>
        <ul class="sub sub-l1">
          <li class="item has-children">
            <input class="input" type="checkbox" name="c3" id="c3">
            <label class="label label-l1" for="c3"><span>Folder 3</span></label>
            <ul class="sub sub-l1">
              <li class="item"><a href="" class="label-l2">Item 3</a></li>
              <li class="item"><a href="" class="label-l2">Item 4</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </aside>
  <div class="main">
    <p>I must speak my mind about this.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```